# Is there a best practice for creation of stored variables within Xcode?

Tags: xcode, variables, initialization

I was wondering if someone could tell me the benefits of creating a local variable first, rather than just initialising a stored variable directly. See example below:

**Example.h**

```
NSString *exampleString;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *exampleString;
```

**Example.m**

```
@synthesize exampleString;
```

**Method 1 (Direct initialisation)**

```
self.exampleString = [NSString stringWithString:@"Example"];
```

**Method 2 (Local initialisation)**

```
NSString *example = [NSString stringWithString:@"Example"];
self.exampleString = example;
[example release];
```

I have used both types within my code but can't notice any direct differences, but when I look at most coding examples they use method 2. I just wondered if there is a practical difference between the two?

Thanks in advanced,
Elliott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method 2, you should not release the `example` variable because you didn't create it nor retained it. Take a look at this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Other than this issue, there is no difference between your two methods. Method 1 is cleaner in my opinion since you don't need that extra variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't think there would be any practical difference but I keep seeing it being done this way and wondered if there was any reason why. Will keep with method 1 for now then!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any for a case where you're only using it once.  In fact, your examples point out a problem in that, if it exists, someone may be tempted to over-release it.  :)

Actually, `self.exampleString = @"Example";` is easier to read than either of them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, does self.exampleString = @"Example" create a retained string?

Comment: The 'retain' on the property definition creates a retained string.

Comment: So the same does not apply when doing my original Example 2?

Comment: Yes, it does.  `self.exampleString = example;` retains the object but then `[example release];` decrements the retain count, bringing you back to a not-retained state.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is wrong! You are releasing an already autoreleased object. You don't own the example string, because you didn't call init or retain. Then you don't need to release it,  or it might crash your app. The correct version of the second method would be:

```
NSString *example = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Example"];
self.exampleString = example;
[example release];
```

The difference between this and your first method is, that here you don't have an autoreleased object. You initialize a string, assign (and retain) it to your instance variable, and then release it. In the first method stringWithString will create an autoreleased object that will be released sometime in the future (usually at the end of a cycle). Until then it's in memory (and wasting it). So especially for (lot's of) big objects, you should avoid this.

Comment: Ah okay, I did wonder if there was a difference between the [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""] and the [NSString stringWithString:@""], I just presumed (foolishly) that the retain would be on both.